# How to use Ltrim Rtrim with 'like operator'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I want to use functions in like operator.

```sql
select * from LG_211_CLCARD where DEFINITION_ like '%LTRIM(RTRIM('test  '))%'
```

Comment: Do you want to trim the value in definition column or trim the value inside user supplised input?

Comment: Putting functions inside a literal string means that would be treated as literal strings. What, however, is the point of trimming the literal string value `'test'`?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want this:

```
SELECT *
FROM LG_211_CLCARD
WHERE DEFINITION_ like CONCAT('%', LTRIM(RTRIM('   test   ')), '%')
```